# Why am I reading zero volts phase to earth?

Tags: electrical

When i measured the voltage reading on the socket I got an unusual reading
phase to neutral is 220V (expected reading )
phase to earth is 0V (unusual) ?? 
neutral to earth is oV (expected reading)

I do not understand why the phase to earth reading shows 0.... Could you please explain the underlying problem

Answer (score 3):

That is a simple "open ground", or "open earth" situation. The safety connection to "earth" is open somewhere in the circuit.

This is a problem that should be corrected. May I ask what prompted you to make these measurements?

Comment: To assist with correcting the "open ground" ... use your multimeter in continuity mode and test between neutral and ground at each device until you find where the ground path is interrupted.

Comment: Thank you for your help... When you said safety connection to earth is open, do you mean that the earth in the plug is not fully connected(circuit broken) to the earthing connection?? After moving into new home the rcb's got tripped, surge protector fried, washer mother board fried... had another electrician measure phase to earth, neutral to earth and phase to neutral to see if anything is amiss..